# Generate Pivot in SQL (Sales per department by hourly slots)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to generate a Pivot in SQL but unable to do so

****This is what I am try to achieve :****

Determine how much was the total sales value (Sum of Value) per Department(1-99) during a given period,based on time intervals(1 hour).

**Note**
Some days the Store opens past midnight and we need to capture the sales everyday for the next day until 2am
How do i include this in my query

This is the PIVOT expected
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qffU.jpg

This is the Data Generated
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTNRC.jpg

From the Data Generated I need to write a query to build the PIVOT

**This is my Query**

```
select * from
(
SELECT  
case 
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 07:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 07:59:59.999' then '07am - 07:59am'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 08:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 08:59:59.999' then '08am - 08:59am'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 09:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 09:59:59.999' then '09am - 09:59am'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 10:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 10:59:59.999' then '10am - 10:59am'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 11:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 11:59:59.999' then '11am - 11:59am'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 12:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 12:59:59.999' then '12pm - 12:59pm'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 13:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 13:59:59.999' then '13pm - 13:59pm'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 14:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 14:59:59.999' then '14pm - 14:59pm'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 15:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 15:59:59.999' then '15pm - 15:59pm'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 16:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 16:59:59.999' then '16pm - 16:59pm'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 17:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 17:59:59.999' then '17pm - 17:59pm'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 18:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 18:59:59.999' then '18pm - 18:59pm'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 19:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 19:59:59.999' then '19pm - 19:59pm'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 20:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 20:59:59.999' then '20pm - 20:59pm'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 21:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 21:59:59.999' then '21pm - 21:59pm'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 22:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 22:59:59.999' then '22pm - 22:59pm'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 23:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 23:59:59.999' then '23pm - 23:59pm'
when [Time] between '1754-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '1754-01-01 00:59:59.999' then '24am - 24:59am'

End [Time Slot],
[Company A$Sales Entries].[Total Rounded Amt_]*-1 ,
[Company A$Item].[Department No_] as Department
FROM            [Company A$Sales Entries] INNER JOIN
                         [Company A$Item] ON [Company A$Sales Entries].[Item No_] = [Company A$Item].No_
WHERE        [Company A$Sales Entries].Date BETWEEN '2017-06-05' AND  '2017-06-06'
and [Company A$Item].[Department No_] in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,50,60,92,93,94,95,96,97,99)

and [POS Terminal] in ('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12')

))as P

        PIVOT (SUM([Company A$Sales Entries].[Total Rounded Amt_])
         for Department in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[50],[60],[92],[93],[94],[95],[96],[97],[99]
                                  )as PVT;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server (MSSQL)? Your SQL code looks to be SQL Server (MSSQL) but you tagged the question with MySQL.

Comment: The question is tagged "MySQL" which is not the same as Microsoft SQL Server; the syntax appears to be Transact-SQL (i.e. Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.)

Comment: Sorry! This was for SQL,Edited the tag

Comment: "Sorry! This was for SQL,Edited the tag"  i added a "answer" might help you out here. Without good table structures, example data and excepted output see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: The <sql> tag is for ANSI/ISO SQL. Your query looks like you should add the <sql-server> tag as well.

Comment: @Sequel3: "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database". Based on the non-standard syntax you used, I added the `sql-server` and `tsql` tags

Answer (score 0):

**Without good table structures, example data and excepted output it is to hard to give a more precise answer**

The most simple SQL way to PIVOT in which all DMBS support is by using this construct.

```
SELECT 
   column
 , MAX(CASE WHEN column = 'value' THEN column ELSE NULL) AS column_name
 , MAX(CASE WHEN column = 'value' THEN column ELSE NULL) AS column_name
 ...
 ...
FROM
 table 
GROUP BY 
 column
ORDER BY
 column
```

Comment: I have provided an example

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SalesValue, Department, Period
FROM (
SELECT SalesValue, Department, Period
FROM <table>) up
PIVOT (SUM(Sales) FOR SalesValue IN (Department, Period)) AS pvt
ORDER BY Period
```

Kindly refer the following link for further help:
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/